# Show message "Setup requires a 64Bit processor" from InstallShield in basic MSI project

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I am using InstallShield 11 and creating a basic MSI project for a 64 Bit machine.

When I run my setup on a 32 Bit machine, the Windows installer shows a message that

> This installation package is not supported by the processor

Now the problem is that I want the InstallShield setup to show another message instead:

> 64bit processor required!

Comment: Does Installshield have a processor property setting that may be set to 64 bit only?

Comment: Ya,Installshield has the function for checking the processor type but i do'nt know how to use it.

Comment: There are also various condition on each dialog box.and we can arrange the sequence also,according to condition.

Comment: I think that the installer package itself is for a 64 bit processor so it cannot execute thus never even staring, so it does not have an opportuiny to check the processor.

Comment: I would try setting for 32bit process only and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mark your install as a 32-bit install rather than a 64-bit install.  (Set "Template Summary" to Intel;1033 rather than AMD64;1033.)

Then, create a Custom Action, conditioned on "Not VersionNT64", which pops up your message "64bit processor required!" and then exits.

This way, your install will still run on 32-bit systems, thus giving you the chance to detect 32-bit/64-bit and take appropriate action.

[VersionNT64 on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

This message is shown automatically by Windows Installer and cannot be customized.

If you really want a custom message, you can try this approach:

- create a custom EXE bootstrapper which determines if the target platform is 32-bit or 64-bit
- if it's 32-bit show your custom message
- if it's 64-bit launch the MSI package

There is no predefined solution, so you would need to write the EXE yourself. Personally, I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: I have been also used custom Action and wizard. but it is not working.

Comment: I didn't mention any custom actions or wizard. Either you create an EXE bootstrapper which launches your MSI, or you leave it like that. You cannot control this from inside your installer.

Comment: Remember, Installshield is just a fancy wrapper for the Microsoft MSI engine.  There's a number of things that are outside your control.